# Client server reconnection issue on CentOS 7

Tags: centos7, rhel5

I am working on a product which has a client server module. One of the regression tests which tests reconnection of the client with the server is failing on CentOS 7 whereas it works fine on RHEL 5 and RHEL 6. What could be the issue here ?

Comment: Is iptables enabled on your CentOS 7? You may also want to check if specific port/ip is allowed on that CentOS 7 as well - Refer [here](http://ask.xmodulo.com/open-port-firewall-centos-rhel.html) for a sample illustration. You also mention it works on RHLE 5 and 6 - Have you tested on CentOS 5 and 6?

Comment: This issue has been resolved, a third party library was the culprit. The versions of this library on RHEL and CentOS were different. Thanks for the help !